# Run 2 times for simulator to start - iOS Simulator failed to install the application

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator

Yesterday I finally got everything set up for sending to testflightapp.com and also setup to upload to Apple.

But now when I click on RUN the app compiles and uploads to the simulator and then the window at the top of XCode says "Attaching to myAppName".  It hangs at that point.  The simulator has nothing on the screen other than the standard desktop.

If I hit RUN the 2nd time, then the app runs right away.  So all day I have been hitting run 2 times. Obviously something is wrong, but haven't a clue where to start.

any ideas?

thanks for any help!

****EDIT: Got this from the console after waiting 2 minutes:**

8/15/11 10:05:01 PM [0x0-0x18018].com.apple.iphonesimulator[262]    MobileInstallationInstall: failed with -1

8/15/11 10:05:01 PM Xcode[143]
Error launching simulated application: 
Error Domain=DTiPhoneSimulatorErrorDomain Code=1 UserInfo=0x2028d71c0 
"iOS Simulator failed to install the application."**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up making a new project copying everything over to the new project. It was easier than spending hours trying to find what change I made :(

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have an idea: Be patient. I have had this too, just wait until the Simulator starts up, 'attatching to ...' means that the Simulator.app is still opening and that xcode is waiting for the Simulator to be fully loaded. So once the simulator is running your app will start to run on the simulator. Just don't close the Simulator.app everytime you have finished running the app, like that you wont have to wait for Simulator to boot up everytime. Also if that still does not work, restart xcode, and simulator or just reboot your mac. Also try deleting your app from the Simulator.

Comment: I have rebooted and also tried restarting everything before that.  The simulator is running, that isnt the problem.  my app that is supposed to be running on the sim only starts up with the 2nd run. I waited 2 minutes for it to attach, and it never happened. It used to start in just a few seconds.

Comment: Try deleting the app on the simulator then.

Comment: I wiped out everything on the simulator using "Reset Contents and Settings"

Comment: Strange, when I had this problem it went away pretty fast using the methods i gave you. What build settings du you have?

Comment: There are lots of build settings, which ones are you wanting me to check?

Comment: Debug or Release? Code signed or not? Developer profile or distribution profile or fake code sign? Try to play around a little bit with the build settings, also with baske sdk and development target.